# How Can I create a select input tag using Buttons and store the selected one in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Here is a snippet of 3 buttons

```
  const [role, setRole] = React.useState('')
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(false)

 <Grid container spacing={1}>
   <Grid item xs={4}>
     <Button variant='plain' value={role} onClick={e => setState(e.target.value)}>
       User
     </Button>
    </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={4}>
     <Button variant='plain' value={role} onClick={e => setState(e.target.value)}>
       Admin
      </Button>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={4}>
    <Button variant='plain' value={role} onClick={e => setState(e.target.value)}>
       Super Admin
    </Button>
  </Grid>
```

What I want to do is toggle between buttons, such that when one is selected, `the other 2 active to false` so i can change the color of the active and inactive buttons

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the `useState` hook wrong. In the beginning, you set up states for `role` and `active`, but then you don't use their set methods (which would be `setRole` and `setActive`). Instead, you use `setState`, which i don't think is defined here.

Apart from that, it seems like you want to track active, as a boolean. That's not going to work, since you need to know which **one of the three** buttons is active.

I suggest changing the state of `active` to an integer. This way, you can number the buttons, and safe the number.

So in each `onClick` method, you call `setActive()` with the correct button number.

E.g.: For button 1:

```
setActive(1);
```

I've tried to show what I mean here:

[codePen Button Toggle Example](https://codepen.io/codingHanna/pen/NWwbqWV)